# Outlook does not recognize one or more names

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have following vba code which reads a mailbox and sends reply to any users who send a invalid code as a reply to the mailbox, but sometimes the run time error (Outlook does not recognize one or more names) is received. My questions are,

1. Will creation of new MAPI profile resolve the issue or do i need to add a code that resolves the address and ignores if the email id no longer exist. if yes how do i do that?
2. Also in general whats the parameter to not send emails for specific condition?

Below is the code that we currently have:

```
      Sub ResponseCodeError(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
      'If not a valid code then send email to the User
      If (Left(Item.Subject, 2) <> "S;" And Left(Item.Subject, 2) <> "N;") Then
      Dim outobj, mailobj
      Set outobj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
      Set mailobj = outobj.CreateItem(0)
      With mailobj
     .To = Item.SenderEmailAddress
     .Subject = "Invalid Code"
     .Body = "Please use a valid CODE"
     .Send
      End With
     'Move Email to Error Folder
     mailboxNameString = "mailboxname"
     FolderName = "Error"

     Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
     Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
     Dim olCurrExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
     Dim olCurrSelection As Outlook.Selection
     Dim olDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

     Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
     Set olCurrExplorer = olApp.ActiveExplorer
     Set olCurrSelection = olCurrExplorer.Selection
     Set olDestFolder = olNameSpace.Folders(mailboxNameString).Folders(FolderName)

     Item.Move olDestFolder

     End If

     Set outobj = Nothing
     Set mailobj = Nothing
     End Sub
```

Comment: So which line of your code raises the exception?

Comment: So the run time error occurs when its in .Send

Comment: What is the value of Item.SenderEmailAddress when that happens?

Comment: I cannot check that as its in our prod environment and cannot put .Display to debug. Its been difficult to reproduce in non-prod environment so just want to see if any code can be put in place to resolve or check email address before sending and not to send email if its invalid or if email address cannot be resolved.

Comment: Instead of setting the To property, call MailItem.Recipients.Add (returns Recipient object). Call Recipient.Resolve  - it will return false if the name cannot be resolved.

Comment: i will give it a try and let you know. Also could you let me know the syntax so as to not to send an email for specific condition, is it just set outobj nothing?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking - if you have a specific condition, you need to explicitly code it.

Answer (score 4):

I had once the same error, and I resolved it after 5 hours searching like crazy in the code. But it was much simpler: 1 email address had an error missing the .(dot) in the domain name.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting the `To` property, call `MailItem.Recipients.Add` (returns `Recipient` object). Call `Recipient.Resolve`  - it will return false if the name cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be due to incorrect names, extra characters or spaces in some property of Item.(especially To, BCC, CC or collective property Recipients)

It might also be due to names not resolved yet before sending the mail. I am not sure but would assume that the error was due to trying to resolve names while sending the mail and probably being unable to resolve them due to some issue. Explicitly resolving names like the code below before the mail is sent should solve the issue.

Item.Recipient.ResolveAll can be used to resolve the names before sending the mail. It returns true if all names were successfully resolved.

Code: ([Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867165.aspx))

```
 If Not myRecipients.ResolveAll Then 

 For Each myRecipient In myRecipients 

 If Not myRecipient.Resolved Then 

 MsgBox myRecipient.Name 

 End If 

 Next 

 End If
```

I have tested the code without adding and resolving recipients 1 by 1.(suggested by Dmitry)

I used Item.To,  Item.BCC properties. Then used ResolveAll and send the mail only if all names are resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this error; code that had been working for years suddenly triggered the "Outlook does not recognize one or more names" error. 
I discovered that the recipient was an Outlook shared folder name, ie. "My Shared Folder" and whether it is an Access 2016 or Outlook issue, the name could no longer resolve to its associated email address. Changing the recipient to "mysharedfolder@blahblah.com" resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED In my case in Outlook I had several contacts with the same e-mail (two companies that are run by one contact/e-mail) and that created the problem. I deleted one of the contacts so no e-mail is repeated in the contact list in Outlook and now it works. Note that my batch still sends an e-mail twice to that contact which info for each company which is what I wanted it.